# Spotify logger for tracks played

Tags: python

I want to share a little app I made that logs tracks I play on Spotify (running in the background on my [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) droplet server). It uses [Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.18.0/), a lightweight Python library for the Spotify Web API. With Spotipy you get full access to all of the music data provided by the Spotify platform.

Any suggestions for improvements are welcome.

`my_spotify_logger.py`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import time
import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import json
from decouple import config
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

TRACK_LOGFILE= Path('logs/track_log.json')
TIME_DELAY = 5
SCOPE = 'user-read-currently-playing'
SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = config('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID')
SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = config('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET')
SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI = config('SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI')

spotify_authorization = SpotifyOAuth(
    SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
    SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI,
    scope=SCOPE,
)
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=spotify_authorization)


@dataclass
class TrackRecord():
    played_at: str
    name: str
    id: int
    artist: str

    def as_dict(self):
        return asdict(self)


def read_track_logfile():
    with open(TRACK_LOGFILE, 'r') as json_file:
        return json.load(json_file)


def update_track_logfile(tracks_log):
    with open(TRACK_LOGFILE, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(tracks_log, json_file)


def print_track(track):
    print(f'{track.played_at}, id: {track.id}\n'
          f'artist: {track.artist}, {track.name}')


def main():
    tracks_log = read_track_logfile()
    track_id = None

    while True:
        new_track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()
        valid_track = (
            new_track and new_track['item'] and track_id != new_track['item']['id']
        )
        if valid_track:
            track_id = new_track['item']['id']
            track_record = TrackRecord(
                played_at=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%B-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                id=track_id,
                artist=new_track['item']['artists'][0]['name'],
                name=new_track['item']['name'],
            )
            print_track(track_record)
            tracks_log['tracks'].append(track_record.as_dict())
            update_track_logfile(tracks_log)

        time.sleep(TIME_DELAY)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using `decouple` you need to define your secret credentials in a `.env` file. Credentials you can get at [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/).

Requirements: python 3.8+

```
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
idna==2.10
python-decouple==3.4
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
spotipy==2.18.0
urllib3==1.26.5
```

Before first time use, you need to initialize your `track_log.json` as

```
{"tracks": []}
```

Finally a nice little app to query json files (in Linux) is `jq`  (`sudo apt install jq`). For example to see the last 3 tracks played.

```
>jq ".tracks[-3:]" ./logs/track_log.json
```

```
[
  {
    "played_at": "2021-June-23 07:37:17",
    "name": "Blitzkrieg Bop - 2001 Remastered Version",
    "id": "33iQW2OneB0oNh2NfrAzqW",
    "artist": "Ramones"
  },
  {
    "played_at": "2021-June-23 07:39:28",
    "name": "Should I Stay or Should I Go - Remastered",
    "id": "3v8PlUFGQQDBIk1J86waCo",
    "artist": "The Clash"
  },
  {
    "played_at": "2021-June-23 07:42:40",
    "name": "Trash",
    "id": "2OQS3xvoKKSayJMJT8dVuZ",
    "artist": "New York Dolls"
  }
]
```